# groups as modules

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let $G$ a abelian group. Prove that $G$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Let $x\in G$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we define $xn$ as follows:

If $n\geq 0$, then $x0=0$ and $x(n+1)=xn+x$. If $n<0$, then $xn=(-x)(-n)$.

Proof:

Let $x,y\in G$ and $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$. So

$(x+y)n=xn+yn$.  How I can distribute the n?

and $x(n+m)=xn+xm$ How I can distribute the x?

Answer (score 1):

You distribute the $n$ and the $x$ by using your very own definition: $$(x+y)(n+1) = (x+y)n + (x+y)$$ for non-negative $n$, and in the second case $$x(n+m+1) = x(n+m) + x$$ for $n+m$ non-negative. Use induction. For the negative case, use induction there too, together with your definition of what $xn$ means for negative $n$.

Comment: but how you can guarantee that $(x+y)n=xn+yn$ and $x(n+m)=xn+xm$?

Comment: By induction. Prove its true for $n = 0$, then prove it holds for each successive case. Then you've proven it for all natural n.

Comment: @user292200 If you have a recursive definition, then that is _begging_ for  proofs by induction.